# How to delete user in laravel 5.7?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm migrating my app from laravel 4.2 to 5.7.
I have this logic to delete a user:
this action is triggred onclick

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})

$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "{{ URL::to('administrator/admin-delete') }}"+"/"+id
});
```

In my route file:

```
Route::delete('admin-delete', 'UsersController@removeAdminDelete');
```

and in my controller:

```
public function removeAdminDelete($id)
{
    $user = Admin::find($id);
    File::delete($user->photo);
    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('successDelete', "ok");
    if(Auth::user()->id == $id){
        Auth::user()->logout();
        return Redirect::to("administrator");
    }else{
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

when i try to remove a user i get this error in my console:

> DELETE my_delete_url 419 (unknown status)!!

After edit i get 404 error !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 419 error in Laravel means that you haven't provided a token for `csrf`.

As shown in the [dos](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) you can add a `meta` tag to the head of your page with the token in:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then set up your ajax requests to include it all the time:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**NB** Make sure you add the above code after you've pulled in jQuery and before you make the ajax request.

---

Furthermore, you should use `delete` and not `resource` for your route.

Change

```
Route::resource('admin-delete', 'UsersController@removeAdminDelete');
```

to

```
Route::delete('admin-delete/{id}', 'UsersController@removeAdminDelete');
```

Comment: i'm editing my question to display the modification i apllied

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya I'd missed off the `id` param for the route. I've updated my answer (specifically the `Route::delete(...)` bit).

Comment: yes that's what causing the problem and also adding the ajaxsetup solved it

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya If this has answered your question please may you mark it as accepted :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is related to csrf token. try to add csrf token in your ajax call like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" id="csrftoken" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and setup your ajax with this header:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('#csrftoken').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Comment: i already put the meta tag in my master layout.How should i add the ajax setup ?

Comment: simply add $.ajaxSetup({ ... }) before your $.ajax({...})

Answer (score 0):

before the closing form tag add this like so

```
<form action='' method='post'>
......
@csrf
</form>
```